# A RuntimeException was generated by the RMI server

Tags: java, spring, jms

I am working on JMS and t3 protocol. JMS is configured with springframework by some properties file. Spring configuration looks like this...

I am using spring3.1.0 version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <bean id="testJndiEnvironment.environment" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
        <property name="jndiName" value="QueueConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
        <property name="jndiName" value="TestTopic"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
        <property name="messageListener">
            <bean id="messageListener" class="com.aires.test.jms.listener.TestMessageListener"/>
        </property>
        <property name="messageSelector">
            <bean id="TestMessageSelector.messageSelector" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

this spring configuration read the message from some other server where JSMServer, Topic and connectionFactory is created.

But springcode is configured it is throwing and exception.

```
<Dec 20, 2016, 1:00:53,139 AM EST> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080003> <A RuntimeException was generated by the RMI server: 1471831785
 java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators].
java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators]
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManagerDelegate2Impl.seal(SecurityServiceManagerDelegate2Impl.java:484)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManagerDelegate2Impl.getSealedSubjectFromWire(SecurityServiceManagerDelegate2Impl.java:177)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.getSealedSubjectFromWire(SecurityServiceManager.java:426)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.getSubject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:360)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.acceptRequest(BasicServerRef.java:996)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I carefully check the providerURL , principal and subject all information are correct. I googled lot of things but could not found any solution. 
could someone help to identify what I am missing here.